# Solidity 0.8.0 - explicit type conversion of address to bytes

Tags: solidity, addresses, type-casting

I am trying to convert an address to bytes so I can perform bitwise operations on the value but noticed that there was a breaking [change](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/breaking/080-breaking-changes.html#new-restrictions:%7E:text=There%20are%20new%20restrictions%20related%20to%20explicit%20conversions%20of%20literals.%20The%20previous%20behaviour%20in%20the%20following%20cases%20was%20likely%20ambiguous%3A) in version 0.8.0. How would I to modify this code to perform operation on the address by converting the `address` value:

```
function register(
      bytes32[] memory _proofs,
      uint8 _bits,
      address _index,
      bytes32 _leaf
    ) internal pure returns (bytes32) {
        require(_index < SIZE, "_index bigger than tree size");
        require(_proofs.length <= DEPTH, "Invalid _proofs length");

        // test bitwise logic
        for (uint256 d = 0; d < DEPTH; d++) {
            if ((_index & 1) == 1) {
              if ((_bits & 1) == 1) {
                _leaf = hash(_proofs[d], _leaf);
              } else {
                _leaf = hash(0, _leaf);
              }
            } else {
              if ((_bits & 1) == 1) {
                _leaf = hash(_leaf, _proofs[d]);
              } else {
                _leaf = hash(_leaf, 0);
              }
            }

            _bits = _bits >> 1;
            _index = _index >> 1;
        }
        return _leaf;
    }
```

This is part of a SMT implementation where I want to have the `index` be an `address` and the leaf be a `uint` value of `1`.

Answer (score 1):

Starting with Solidity 0.8.0 you can no longer convert the address directly to bytes32. You have to perform two separate conversions: first to bytes20, which changes the type from address to fixed bytes, and only then to bytes32 which extends the length.

```
bytes32(bytes20(address))
```

Comment: I should also include that `SIZE` variable is of type uint256 and I would now be comparing that to bytes32 with your changes which is not allowed. How can i solve this?

Comment: I'm sorry but I do not understand. Can you explain with an example?

Comment: This was solved by `uint256(uint160(_index))`. The problem was I was comparing `bytes` to `uint` which is not allowed.